# 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' after returning from Laravel password reminder

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, passwords

This is my home page route, where I get a random member:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $member = User::orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->first();
    return View::make('landing', compact('member'));
});
```

When the `RemindersController`'s `postRemind` method sends the email, I'm doing this:

```
case Password::REMINDER_SENT:
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_message', 'Whatever message...');
```

And the home page returns:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected (SQL: select * from `users` order by RAND() asc limit 1)
```

If I refresh the page right there, it fixes itself..
I'm using `getenv()` and `.env.php` files to fill the database connection values. If I switch from that to hard code them in, it fixes the problem. And if I go back to using `getenv()` it works too. However, as soon as I restart WAMP, I'm back to square 1.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I replaced the hard coded values in database.php by using getenv().

Are you sure that is loading the correct environment? you can check it in the terminal going to the route of your project and doing

> php artisan env

If is not the correct one, you can fix it in the file start.php

For example, if your local environment file (in the root of your project) is called ".env.local.php" in the file start.php you should have something like

> $env = 'yourHostName.local'

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily solve this problem by adding the **database name** and **username** and **password** in the root folder **.env** file.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but only occurs when I have several users simultaneously accessing the site (with around 10++ users). Here's the error message: `exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' C:\laravel\..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:292` On my database.php, values for database, username and password are coming from my `.env` file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem you only have to change APP_ENV in .env file

```
APP_ENV=localhost.local
```